# PHP Code inside HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

what is wrong in following code as when I remove the php variable $var every thing work but I need to insert the id value which equals 5000 in a PHP variable $var

```
echo '<div id="img1" style="position:absolute;left:81px;top:127px;width:12px;height:12px;z-index:65;"><a href="#" onclick="$(\'#jQueryDialog1\').dialog(\'open\');return false;"><img src="img/image.png"'.$var=.' id="5000" alt="" style="width:12px;height:12px;"></a></div>';
```

Comment: Remove '=' after $var.

Comment: remove the `=` ... is invalid

Comment: I want to put the image id value whatever it is in a PHP variable called $var                    $var=id=$value

Comment: You can not assign a value to any variable in between echo this HTML. Just assign this value before your echo. $var = 'id = "5000"';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `=` its causing 1 of the errors
2. The variable is being inserted out of the `id="x"` part of the  tag
3. Remember PHP is CASE SENSITIVE that means `$var` isn't the same as `$Var` or `$VAR`

Here is the correct code:

```
$var = 5000;
echo '<div id="img1" style="position:absolute;left:81px;top:127px;width:12px;height:12px;z-index:65;"><a href="#" onclick="$(\'#jQueryDialog1\').dialog(\'open\');return false;"><img src="img/image.png" id="'.$var.'" alt="" style="width:12px;height:12px;"></a></div>';
```

Comment: ok thank you but what if I want to insert the image id in a PHP variable for example $var=5000 then id=5000 then $new_var=id
N.B I dont want to $new_var=$var

Comment: PHP can't run on the client, so if you wanted to retrieve the ID after it being sent to the browser you'd need to use JavaScript, but if you want to retrieve it before its sent, you'll need to store the HTML you're printing and use a PHP HTML parser for that. The easiest solution would be `$new_var=$var`

Comment: yes i want the solution of retrieving the image id after it being sent to the browser through javascript and then insert it in a PHP variable

any help please also thank you very very much for your cocerns

Comment: You could use JavaScript to retrieve the ID of the image, then send an AJAX request to another PHP file so it could be saved in a variable. Or use JavaScript to retrieve the ID and save it into a cookie.

Comment: ok I'm new to web development all I want to get the id of the user clicked image and store it in a file or database or php variable in order to select a record from the database by the image id as a reference

Comment: ok, so I recommend you search these things to achieve that: `JavaScript AJAX requests`, `PHP $_GET`, `PHP Session variables`. With these you should be able to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What's up with the "=" in .$var=. 
Remove it.

```
$var = '5000'
echo '<div id="img1"style="position:absolute;left:81px;top:127px;width:12px;height:12px;z-index:65;"><a href="#" onclick="$(\'#jQueryDialog1\').dialog(\'open\');return false;"><img src="img/image.png"'. $var .' id="5000" alt="" style="width:12px;height:12px;"></a></div>';
```

Not sure the HTML is correct.

Comment: first of all thanks for your support then

when I removed it the following error appeared

Notice: Undefined variable: var

and when I didn't remove the following error appeared

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

I want to insert the id value in the $Var

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$var = 5000;
echo '<div id="img1" style="position:absolute;left:81px;top:127px;width:12px;height:12px;z-index:65;"><a href="#" onclick="$(\'#jQueryDialog1\').dialog(\'open\');return false;"><img src="img/image.png" id="' . $var . '" alt="" style="width:12px;height:12px;"></a></div>';
```